# Redirect URL A to URL B

Tags: mvc, iis, redirect, routing, url-rewrite

I want to redirect one URL to the another. Suppose, I have 2 URLs

1. www.abc.com/home/gateway [Item for **/gateway** is not created in sitecore]
2. www.xyz.com/newgateway.php [This is not a Sitecore Webpage]

So, here I want to redirect URL 1 to URL 2. In URL 1, /gateway item is not created but here I want if anybody hits that exact URL 1 it automatically redirected to URL 2.

I tried the IIS URL Rewrite module, it is not working correctly showing 404 Sitecore Error.

My Rule:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="My Rewrite" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="/home/gateway" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="www.xyz.com/newgateway.php" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: @MarekMusielak I tried iisrewrite but is showing 404 error in Sitecore not redirecting.

Comment: Use `<match url="home/gateway" />` without `/` at the beginning

Comment: @MarekMusielak I tried but same error. Showing 404 error page not redirecting to the URL 2.

Comment: Are you testing it in a fresh private browsing window each time? It's possible that your browser has cached the response. (You could also use Fiddler to make sure you're issuing a fresh request every time.)

Comment: Yes, I am using Incognito everytime.

Comment: Action type should be Redirect instead of Rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative you can write your own processor. For example like you would create a 404 processor, but then let it hook into a Sitecore list where you map url's to external links.

Like:

```
public class NotFoundRedirectProcessor: HttpRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        if (Sitecore.Context.Item != null || Sitecore.Context.Site == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (string.Equals(Sitecore.Context.Site.Properties["enableCustomErrors"], "true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == false)
        {
            return;
        }

        var redirectUrl = GetRedirectUrl(args);
        if (redirectUrl  != null)
        {
          WebUtil.Redirect(redirectUrl, false);
          args.AbortPipeline();
        }

        var pageNotFound = this.Get404PageItem();
        args.ProcessorItem = pageNotFound;
        Sitecore.Context.Item = pageNotFound;
    }

    protected Item Get404PageItem()
    {
        // This is largely up to how the project in general is setup.
        // My solutions are heavily Fortis dependent, but for Vanilla 
        // Sitecore setups you could just use the following setting:
        // Settings.GetSetting("ItemNotFoundUrl", "/errors/404");
        // and pull the Item object from that path

        var path = Sitecore.Context.Site.RootPath + "/" + Settings.GetSetting("ItemNotFoundUrl", "/errors/404");
        var item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(path);

        return item;
    } 

    private string GetRedirectUrl(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {  
      //Add your code here to resolve from your Sitecore list the right url to redirect to
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using the [Sitecore Url Rewrite module](https://github.com/iamandycohen/UrlRewrite) which allows you to configure [IIS Url Rewrites](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) in Sitecore items.

Comment: I tried to install the module you shared but it is throwing this error while installation -  "The parent item of /sitecore/templates/User Defined/Url Rewrite/Redirect Folder/Site was not serialized. You cannot have a sparse serialized tree. You may need to serialize this item's parents."

Comment: I'm not familiar with that error, but did you try serializing the parents?

Comment: No, I was just installing the package "URL Rewrite-1.8.2.zip", this error was thrown by sitecore installation wizard.

Comment: I would try serializing the parents, then, to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: It's also possible that that module does not support your version of Sitecore. It looks like it has been updated to work with 8.2, but may not have been tested with 9+.

Comment: I am using Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 160519), is there any other module or way to redirect without creating processor?

Comment: It should work with your version of Sitecore (I've used it with that specific version). I would try doing what the error says and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Okay I will check what is causing it to break, and update here.